# Why $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \times P(B | A) \times P(C | A \cap B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I need help to intuitively understand that $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \times P(B | A) \times P(C | A \cap B)$? Why it's true?

Comment: By definition $\mathbb P(A\mid B)=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)}$, and thus $$\mathbb P(A\cap B)=\mathbb P(A\mid B)\mathbb P(B).$$ The claim follows by induction.

Comment: Start with the easier question: **intuitively**, why is $p(A\cap B) = p(A) \times p(B|A)~$ ?  It is because once you know that event $A$ has occurred, you do not care about the general probability of event $B$ occurring.  You only care about the probability of event $B$ occurring, given the presumption that event $A$ has occurred.

Comment: In order for all of $A,B,C$ to occur you need first for $A$ to occur, then for $B$ to occur (knowing that $A$ has already occurred), and then for $C$ to occur (knowing that $A,B$ have already occurred).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Intuitive explanation / example

Here's an example that might help with the intuition: If I draw three cards without replacement from a standard deck, what is the probability that all three cards are hearts?

Let $A, B, C$ be the events that the first, second, and third cards are hearts, respectively.

If I want all three cards to be hearts, then I need:

- my first card to be hearts; $\mathbb P(A) = 13/52$
- my second card to be hearts, given that my first was: $\mathbb P(B \mid A) = \frac{12}{51}$
- my third card to be hearts, given that my first two were: $\mathbb P(C \mid A \cap B) = \frac{11}{50}$

The probability of all three happening is the product of all three probabilities, or $\frac{12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50}.$ The intuition is that you're "chaining" each probability computation on previous ones, and as you do so you predicate each computation on the previous ones having occurred.

---

#### Algebraic explanation

By definition,
$$\mathbb P(D \cap E) = \mathbb P(D) \cdot \mathbb P(E \mid D)$$
so applying this definition with events $D = C$ and $E = A \cap B$ gives
$$\mathbb P(C \cap B \cap A) = \mathbb P(A \cap B) \cdot \mathbb P(C \mid A \cap B)$$
and applying the definition on the inner term with $D = A$ and $E = B$ gives the desired result.